# Divergence of $x |x|^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I have a problem proving the following:

Given is a function $u: \mathbb{R}^n \backslash  0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $
with $u(x)= x |x|^{-n}$

Now i need to show that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n  \backslash  0$

$$\operatorname{div} u(x) = 0$$

To be honest i dont even know how to start. Can anyone help me to prove that? It seems to be simple but apparently im stuck at the moment

Comment: Do you know the definition of divergence?
\begin{align}
\text{div }u&=\nabla\cdot u\\
&=\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}+... \qquad \text{where }\,(x_1,x_2,x_3,..., x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment you can directly apply the formula for the divergence:
$$\operatorname{div} (u ) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k}$$
as $$u_k(x)=x_k |x|^{-n}=x_k \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 \right)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$$
you obtain:
$$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k}=|x|^{-n}-\frac{n}{2} x_k \times \frac{2 x_k}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 \right)^{-\frac{n}{2}+1}}=\frac{1}{|x|^{n+2}} \left( |x|^2-n x_k^2\right) $$
summing over $k$:
$$\operatorname{div}(u)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|x|^{n+2}} \left( |x|^2-n x_k^2\right) =\frac{1}{|x|^{n+2}} \left(n |x|^2- n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)=0 $$

---

**Remark**

This straightforward approach is probably one of the least efficient, you can for example use the formula for the divergence of a radial function or a intrinsic approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow the approach with the formula seemed to be too obvious.